# How to create a Zip file on a remote server in perl

Tags: perl

actualy im using  Net::FTP::Recursive to download a directory structure , it works nice for what is required. But since some folders have more than 100/ files, downloading then can take ages. Since a zip file is faster do download, how i could, using perl connect to a remote server via ftp and create a zip file from the remote server/folder  to download ?

```
use Net::Config;
use Net::FTP::Recursive;


$ftp = Net::FTP::Recursive->new("$hostname:$ftp_port",  Debug => 0)
or die "Cannot connect to $hostname: $@";
$ftp->login($iLogin,$iPass)
or die "failed ", $ftp->message;
$ftp->binary()
or die "Cannot set to Binary";
$ftp->cwd("/admin/packages/$fileName")
or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;
$ftp->rget( $fileName );
#or die "Download Failed ", $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit;
```

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **site(ARGS)** method is designed for that. You can send a shell command and make it runs on remote server.
http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html#METHODS

However, most of the FTP servers I know disabled that permission, so, good luck

Comment: Hi, 

exclusive unix solutions wont be the case since the servers are unix or nt. the only way i get to connect is by ftp

Comment: @ThalesPereira, this solution is per standard FTP protocol, not exclusive Unix solution, it should work for NT.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to have SSH access to the system to run a ZIP command. But if that's the case, you could also use SCP to transfer your files more securely. FTP does everything in the open.

Thanks,

F.

Comment: Hi, 

exclusive unix solutions wont be the case since the servers are unix or nt. the only way i get to connect is by ftp